# fchmod() unable to apply file permissions correctly in C

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

This is the partial code where I am trying to apply permissions to file.

```
fd=fopen(file_name,"wb");
fchmod(fd,(mode_t)perm);
```

Where perm is an integer . ex: 644 or 755
I tried without casting with mode.

Comment: Did you listen to your compiler at all?  Even at the default settings, your compiler should be warning you with something like "`warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'FILE *' (aka 'struct __sFILE *') to parameter of type 'int'`".  That should be a big red flag that something is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the already-mentioned issue of using octal constants, you are calling `fchmod` incorrectly - the prototype is:

```
 int
 fchmod(int fildes, mode_t mode);
        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

but you are passing a `FILE *` (as returned by `fopen`) for the first parameter! Either use `open` instead of `fopen`, so that you get an `int fildes` to play with, or use `chmod` with the file name.

There are two important take-home message here:

1. you should always enable compiler warnings, and take heed of any warnings. If you had done this then it would have been immediately obvious that you were calling `fchmod` incorrectly.
2. calls like `fchmod` return a status - you should not ignore this! It will most likely be non-zero in your case, as you passed an invalid `fildes` parameter. So even if the code had been correct, you would still have learned something from the non-zero status.

Answer (score 1):

That should be `0644` or `0755`.  Those are octal constants for them to make sense that way.

0644 means read/write (6) to owner; read only to group and world.

0755 means read/write/execute (7) to owner; read/execute to group and world.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to apply file permission you need to use octal values! when you use integer values, its invalid

Try this-

```
int perm = 0644; // or use mode_t perm = 0644;

fd=fopen(file_name,"wb"); 
fchmod(fd,perm);
```